# What does dot and dotdot means

Tags: windows, qt

What is the meaning of dot and dotdot when listing folders using QDir::entryList?
It is not really obvious to me.

Comment: Dot is the current directory, dotdot is the parent directory.  Most file managers hide them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.` means "current directory" and `..` means "parent directory".

For example, if your directory is `C:\Users\Bob`, `.` refers to `C:\Users\Bob` and `..` refers to `C:\Users`.

You will find that this is universal in programming and computers in general.

If you don't want your list to contain these special directories, you can include `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` in your filter.

Answer (score 3):

Dot means the folder currently set for QDir, dotdot refers to the parent folder. You often do not want ro list those in your algorithms, so it is possible to request entryList not to return those.